# "INVALID_ARGUMENT: URI '' not a valid Compute resource URI." when creating single node cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

When running the following command (which has been running fine for weeks):

`gcloud beta dataproc clusters create our-dataproc-cluster \
  --bucket project-bucket \
  --zone europe-west1-b \
  --single-node \
  --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
  --master-boot-disk-size 500 \
  --image-version 1.1 \
  --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' \ 
  --project our-project-name`

I now get this error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataproc.clusters.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: URI '' not a valid Compute resource URI.`

The command I'm running is the same one generated at the creation page:
[image]

The error seems to only occur for single node clusters.

Comment: We're looking into this and will post an update soon.

Comment: We apologize for inconvenience this has caused. We've identified the issue and are rolling out a fix. It should be available in the next few days. In the mean time, configuration with 2 small workers will at least unblock you: --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the swift reply.